# Introductory text on numerical analysis

Tags: soft-question, numerical-methods

I was wondering if anyone has a good suggestion for a textbook on numerical analysis. I am an undergraduate with little prior knowledge about topics in numerical analysis since I have never taken a formal course in the subject; and I probably will not have time to given my schedule. I would like to spend some time over winter break/summer break learning the material myself. Thus, the ideal text would be written for an undergraduate audience that is easily accessible for someone who may not have a professor to ask questions for clarification. Furthermore, it would be preferred if the text did not require some sort of software (e.g. MatLab, Mathematica, etc.) as I may not have access to such software.

Comment: Can you tell us what knowledge about multivariate analysis, linear algebra and differential equations you already have? Many resources use Matlab, but insead of that you can use the opensource version called octave, which has a syntax that is pretty much compatible with matlab (apart from a few details).

Comment: I have taken introductory courses (college level) in multivariable calculus, differential equations (ODE; taught some PDE to myself) and linear algebra. I am currently in the first half of a two-semester real analysis course, and I plan on taking the second half next semester.